# jQuery TimePicker - using dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, timepicker

Has anyone used Trent Richardsons TimePicker?

It's a wonderful plugin, but I just can't seem to change the format of the date to dd/mm/yyyy

Has anyone used this control and knows if this can be done?

Comment: Got a link to the plugin page?

Comment: Sure: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this works

```
>  DatePicker2.datepicker({ dateFormat:
> 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true,
> changeYear: true, showAnim: '',
> showTime: true, duration: ''
>             });
```

Comment: That's perfect!!! Didn't realise I could add the dateFormat within the curly brackets.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `dateFormat` on the `TimePicker` object itself.

```
$.datepicker.regional['en'] = {
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
}
```